# Resolve ambiguous reference in C#

Tags: c#, wcf

I am working on a WCF client where i have 2 service references.Both service references have a common method names.I have GetNames() in both of my service references.Since i have to instantiate based on the condition ,I am trying to do the following:

```
IF Yes

Serviceclient1.GetNames name1= new Serviceclient1.GetNames();

Else

ServiceClient2.GetNames name2 =new Serviceclient1.GetNames();
```

But I am getting ambiguous reference even though i am referring to two different namesspaces ?

I would be glad if some one can guide me here ?

Comment: What is the *exact* error message you're receiving?

Comment: `GetNames()` looks like a method name, but you're using it like a class name.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Its a class.

Comment: What is `IF Yes` and `Else`? In your last line, the `name2` is set to something with a `1` in it, but its type has the `2`. Is this your exact code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do one of the following:

1) Fully qualify `Serviceclient1`, as in:

```
var name1 = new Namespace.Serviceclient1.GetNames();
```

2) Add a `using` statement like the following:

```
using SomeAlias = Namespace.Serviceclient1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try aliasing your conflicting reference.

```
using ServiceCient2 = Namespace.Serviceclient1;
```

From MSDN, [How to: Use the Global Namespace Alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx)